# C# Gecko Allow Notifications

Tags: notifications, gecko, geckofx

I am using the Geckofx 45 in C# for a webpage to render.
My web app will send notification messages.

I am having trouble to accept the notifications and show in the browser.

Notification.Persmission should be kept granted for a page to load.

I am trying to set User preferences for Gecko Browser
 Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["notification.feature.enabled"] = true;
 Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["dom.webnotifications.enabled"] = true;

But still the notifications are not accepted.

How to enable notifications in the Gecko Browser.

Appreciate for the suggestions.